# I am doing some web scraping and during that I've run into an error whih states that, "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, non-type

I am using bs4 for web scraping. This is the html code that I am scraping.
`items` is a list of these multiple div tags i.e `<div class="list_item odd" itemscope=""...>`
from which the tag that I really want from each in `items` element is:

```
<p class="cert-runtime-genre">
                        
            <img title="R" alt="Certificate R" class="absmiddle certimage" src="https://m...>
            <time datetime="PT119M">119 min</time>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span>Drama</span>
            <span class="ghost">|</span>
            <span>War</span>
                            
 </p>
```

The `main` class of this list is saved in `items`. From that I want to **scrape** the `img` tag and then access the `title` attribute so that I can save all the certifications of the movies in a database i.e R or PG etc. But when I apply loop to the `items` it gives an error that the `items` is not subscriptable. I tried list comprehensions, simple for loop, called `items` elements through a predefined integer array nothing works and still gives the same error. (`items` is not Null and is subscriptable i.e. is a list). But when I call it with a direct integers it works fine i.e `items[0]` or `items[1]` etc, and gives the correct result for each corresponding element in the `items` list. The error line is below:

`cert = [item.find(class_ = "absmiddle certimage")["title"] for item in items]` or
`cert = [item.find("img",{"class": "absmiddle certimage"})["title"] for item in items]`
and this is what works fine: `cert = items[0].find(class_ = "absmiddle certimage")["title"]`
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: `find` must be returning `None`, indicating that it didn't find anything.

Comment: `cert = items[0].find(class_ = "absmiddle certimage")["title"]`   or  `cert = items[1].find(class_ = "absmiddle certimage")["title"]`  works fine that means that find is actually not returning None for individual elements but giving an error when loop is applied.

Comment: I suspect that there are more `items` then you think then, and one past the first two are causing the error.

Comment: Yup you are right found the mole. Can delete or close this conversation if you want. Thanks.

Comment: There's a delete button at the bottom of the question. You could write an answer too if you were willing to add some detail about what the problem is.

Comment: Sir I cannot find a solution for it. I want to search all  `img`  tags with  `absmiddle certimage`  class having  `title`  attribute and if there is any null value, I mean if it is not present in the list, it should return something instead of making the whole list a not subscriptable object.

Comment: That'll be hard for a list comprehension. The cleanest way would be to use a full `for` loop instead, then do something like `result = item.find(class_ = "absmiddle certimage"); if result: results.append(result ["title"])` in the loop; where `results` is an empty list define outside of the loop. Then `results` will holds the results.

Comment: To use a comprehension, you'd be need to use the `:=` operator or something else that achieves the same, which would likely negate the readability benefits of the comprehension.

Comment: Is this from a particular website?

Comment: I am scraping "IMDB New Movies in theaters" this week page. Your code worked perfectly and Null values were replaced too. Can you Explain this piece of code here in detail? And should I now post an answer with your proposed code to me? Thanks.